# Some tricky path integrals without residue theory

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

I am trying to work out the following path integrals without residue theory and have a really hard time doing so:
\begin{align*}
            \int_{\partial K_2(0)}\frac{e^{iz^2}-1}{z^2}dz
            \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
            \int_{\partial K_1(i)}\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z^2+1)^2}dz
            \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
            \int_{\partial K_3(0)}\left(e^z+\frac{\cos(z)}{z}\right)^3dz
        \end{align*}
Where $\partial K_i(z_0)$ is the contour of a circle wtih radius i around the point $z_0$.
I tried applying Cauchy's integral formula, but I always get stuck. Does anyone have an advice on how to solve these? Another idea was to show the functions inside of the integral are holomorphic, so all of the integrals would be $0$. E.g. the first function $\frac{e^{iz^2}-1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ as a composition of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, so the integral disapears.
**UPDATE**
After getting the hint to use the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives, I tried the same for the second integral. Notice that: \begin{align} \int_{\partial K_1(i)}\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z^2+1)^2}dz =\int_{\partial K_1(i)}\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{((z-i)(z+i))^2}\end{align} So I tried using $f(z)=\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z+i)^2}$ as my function. For the formula (see answer below) and with that I get \begin{align}f'(i)=\frac{-\pi sin(\pi i)(2i)-cos(\pi i)\cdot 2}{-8i}=-\frac{1}{4}i cosh(\pi) + \frac{1}{4} π i sinh(π)\end{align}
From here on I can't seem to work it out any further. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What are $K_j$ ($j=1,2,3$)? Have you tried the Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives of a function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those integrals disapear since $0$ and $i$ are interior points of your contours, so it could be a priori wrong. You could use Cauchy's formula for derivatives. For the first integral we use, $$f^{(n)} (z) = \dfrac{n!}{2 \pi i } \int_C \dfrac{f(w)}{(w - z)^{n + 1}} \ dw, \ \ n = 0, 1, 2, ... \nonumber,$$ with $f(z)=e^{iz^2}-1$ and $n=1$. So $$ \int_{\partial K_2(0)}\frac{e^{iz^2}-1}{z^2}dz=2\pi i f'(0)=0,$$ that makes sense since the limit at $z=0$ exists.
For the last one lets take $f(z):=(ze^z+\cos z)^3.$ By the Cauchy's formula $$\int_{\partial K_3(0)}\left(e^z+\frac{\cos(z)}{z}\right)^3dz=\pi if''(0)=9\pi i.$$

Comment: It is possible that the residues sum to zero or that the residues are zero. If a contour encloses poles, that doesn't imply the contour integral is nonzero

Comment: That's the reason why i wrote "so it could be a priori wrong"

Comment: "None of those integrals disappear since..." suggests that it is obvious (without further calculation) all the integrals are nonzero

Comment: That's true, I didnt explain it well. Thank you!

Comment: One again, what is $\partial K_r(0)$ ? Is $K$ the initial of the german word Kugel (with center $0$ and radius $r$) ?

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry I didn't clarify that, I edited my question now.

Comment: I did it with a calculator so im pretty sure